Pasting into a filtered range - how to prevent hidden cells from changing
Which of the following methods will not change the values of the hidden cells in a range of a filtered column?

Copy value, select entire range in filtered column, Paste value
Copy value, select first cell in range in filtered column, paste value, drag the plus sign in the bottom right corner of the cell to fill the rest of the cells with that value
Copy value, select first cell in range in filtered column, paste value, Ctrl + Shift + DownArrow to highlight the entire range, Ctrl + D

Or is there another way?
I messed up a file somehow by accidentally filling the hidden cells within the ranges as well as the visible cells. I'm not entirely sure how, though. I've tried duplicating the error in a test file, but have been unable to do so.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
